# Can I bridge the iPhone wireless signal with a router to use it with ethernet cable?

Tags: wifi, tethering, router

I have a tp-link router with bridge option. I would like to connect with the router to iphone's wifi signal, and share it to an NVR using the ethernet cable. Is it possible? I tried it with TP-Link TL-WR741ND, but unfortunately the internet connection doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no, you cannot do this. However, I would like to believe there are different options for what you are trying to accomplish.

I am not too familiar with NVR's, however you should be able to bridge your connection from your iPhone to a laptop, via Wifi, and after that be able to bridge your laptop's connection to your NVR.

I wouldn't imagine it would be the most reliable thing in the world, but should work.

Steps to attempt this:

1. Create a hotspot with your iPhone. Settings > Personal Hotspot (Enable)
2. Connect to it with your laptop
3. Bridge your connection! *Helpful links to bridge your connection below*
   http://www.countrymilewifi.com/how-to-share-computers-wifi-with-ethernet-devices.aspx
   http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10